# How to verify whether existing token about to expire in java

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, token, access-token

How to verify whether existing token about to expire in java and get another new access token before it expires?

I already searched on google on above, found some answer as take expiry time of access token, and write some logic based on system time matching with expiry time, so if current time about to near expiry time, then make a backend call to get new access token. I am not asking how to get new access token using refresh token, for which I already had backend code which takes care of it. All I need is to know when to make a ajax call using java when access token about to expire..

Please tell me is there any better approach for above?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you describe? Whenever you make a call, check to see whether or not your token is expired or about to expire. If so, get a new one.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Assume , token expire time is 30 mins.. Is that correct to depend on our System time? should I calculate like current time + 30 mins, then make a call orelse  current time + 25 mins, then make a call , reduced 5 mins wantedly so that to avoid redirecting to login page, which is correct?

Comment: Take a little bit of buffer. I'm personally also using 25 minutes for a 30 minute token to be on the safe side.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Any sample code can you provide.. as I am not finding anywhere.. wondering how to write perfect logic to handle..

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you pls? atleast your own some part of proj logic code..

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty. The `expires_in` property contains the number of seconds the token will be valid. This allows you to calculate when it expires. You hold on to that value somewhere and every time you use it, you check whether or not it has expired or is about to expire.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I read somewhere that instead of writing logic for expiryTime on client side, instead we can verify "accesstoken expiry" using Error code like 400 or 401.. Please find more details in the link provided and also please let me know your thoughts as well.. Here is the link: https://rnd.feide.no/2012/04/19/best-practice-for-dealing-with-oauth-2-0-token-expiration-at-the-consumer/

Comment: You will need that approach anyway, regardless of expiry time. The token might no longer be valid, even if according to your calculations it hasn't expired yet. This could happen e.g. if the remote server keeps its tokens in memory and has been restarted. I use a combination of both approaches to be able to distinguish between cases where the token that has actually expired, and cases where the remote server is not honoring its obligations.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think checking errorcode on frontend shud be enuf. for eg: if true for errorcode == 401 , then I make a backend ajax call to get new accessToken. IMO, this should be enuf, I really didnt understood whats the need to calculate expiry time from front end, no need to calculate accesstoken expirytime when we are already verifying with errorcode which never gives us false value..  If we are considering time calculation approach (say for 25 mins), what if accesstoken got expired due to any reason? then you will never make backend ajax call till 25 mins..  This is just my opnion..

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the expiration date based on the expires_in value in the response and store both the access token and expiration date in memory. Before using the access token check if it has expired, fetch a new one if expired and store the same in memory.
You can also write a scheduler which runs in the background and fetches the access token before it expires.